# bootstrap fixed header when scrolling down

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working within bootstrap's core admin structure and have a main header at the top of the page and then a sub header beneath it. I am trying to allow that sub header to fix to the top of the page when the user scrolls down so they can always see that information, but I am having a bit of trouble.

The section I would like to stick to the top looks like this.

```
<div class="area-top clearfix" >
  <div class="pull-left header">
    <h3 class="title"><i class="icon-group"></i>Dashbord</h3>
  </div><!--.header-->
  <ul class="inline pull-right sparkline-box">
    <li class="sparkline-row">
      <h4 class="blue"><span> Cover Designs</span> 4</h5>
    </li>
    <li class="sparkline-row">
      <h4 class="green"><span> Video Trailers</span> 5</h5>
    </li>
    <li class="sparkline-row">
      <h4 class="purple"><span> Web Banners</span> 5</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!--.area-top-->
```

and I have tried so far to wrap that in another div with the `navbar navbar-fixed-top` classes. But that shot it to the top right away and overlapped content that needs to be seen.

I have also tried using plain css by adding `position:fixed;` to the current div, but that messes up the breadcrubms I have laying underneath it because it takes it out of the flow.

Is there anyway to accomplish this with just css. I know I can do a hack with jquery, but in my team I am only in charge of the css.

Comment: If you use `navbar-fixed-top` you have to add padding to the <body> with the height of navbar. Eg: if you `navbar` `height` is `50p`x the  you have to add `50px` padding to body.

Comment: @AvinVarghese It still doesn't work for this situation because I don't want it to stretch across the entire page because it hides content and takes it out of the flow of the page. Plus this only happens on one page so I don't want to add padding globally.

Comment: Can you provide you sample code in http://bootply.com/new

Comment: @AvinVarghese it's in core admin so it won't show up right in that format. It's a paid template.

Answer (score 2):

you can use below css to the sub header navbar.

css:

```
.sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
}
```

Add 'sticky-top' class to sub header.

for eg: you can see the fiddle below which is similar to the question.Here second menu fixed to top when user scrolls.

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/awknd20r/6/

Comment: Also useful to add an opaque colour to the background such as: background-color: white;

Answer (score 0):

position:fixed is the way to go here. Can you apply a height to the div you want to be fixed and apply a margin to the breadcrumbs?

```
.area-top{ position:fixed; height:2em; }

.breadcrumbs { margin-top: 2.2em; }
```

Comment: This still lays the nav right on top of the breadcrumbs even though it has the margin top on it

Comment: Are the breadcrumbs being pushed down on the page at all? Either the style isn't being applied, or a larger margin should be specified.

Comment: the breadcrumbs are staying right underneath the heading and the heading is being pushed down the page. I put it inline styles so I could make sure it was being applied and in the web inspector added over 20em on margin to see if anything would happen, but they both moved down the page the breadcrumbs under the header.

Comment: Can you post the HTML / CSS for the breadcrumbs so we can see what other styles are in play?

Answer (score -1):

My point of view is the following. When you ask for this :

`to fix to the top of the page when the user scrolls down`

It means that you need to detect when users are scrolling. Furthermore, there is no other way than js / jQuery to detect this kind of action. CSS can be a part of solution by creating a class for exemple which will stick your menu, but you'll always need a bit of js to detect when to put and to remove the class.

Here is an exemple on how to do this in jQuery :

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var offset = $('.area-top').offset().top;
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(top >= offset){
            // this is where you should fix you menu
            $('.area-top').addClass('fixed'); // if you have a css class which fix the element.
            $('.area-top').css('position', 'fixed'); // if you don't have css class
        }else{
            // this is where you should unfix your menu
            $('.area-top').removeClass('fixed'); // if you have a css class which fix the element.
            $('.area-top').css('position', 'inherit'); // if you don't have css class
        }
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget that every "advanced" action which need to detect a change in the DOM or which need an user interaction will require some JS or PHP to deal with it. By "advanced", i'm meaning all the things that can't be natively handle in HTML.